# Epoch time into date/time format

Tags: c, datetime, epoch

I have a char holding an epoch time, I am trying to convert this into the date/time format of YYYY/mm/dd/HH:MM:SS,

I have been using strftime but can't seem to get it right,

Can anyone give me a hand?

```
            time_t eventFinish = endTime;
            struct tm *tm2 = localtime(&eventFinish);
            //syslog( LOG_INFO, "eventFinish:: %s", eventFinish);
            char buf2[64];
            strftime( buf2, sizeof( buf2 ), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", &tm2 );
            syslog( LOG_INFO, "Your time: %s", buf2 );
```

eventFinish outputs the epoch time I am expecting, buf2 outputs random numbers.

Comment: can you show what you have tried and what the result was? Maybe someone can spot a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert your unix timestamp into a `struct tm` first

```
time_t ts = 1562230784; // current time as example
struct tm *tm = localtime(&ts);
```

and then use this with `strftime()`:

```
char buf[64];
strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y/%m/%d/%H:%M:%S", tm);
printf("Your time: %s\n", buf);
```

The relevant structures are defined in `time.h`.
This should about do what you want.

Note that this will return the time in the local timezone configured in your system. To get UTC, you can use `gmtime()` instead of `localtime()`.

Comment: Thanks you have helped me a lot, I've added a code snippet as I'm still not getting the correct result

Comment: @GrantJamieson Review this `strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y/%m/%d/%H:%M:%S", tm);` and your `strftime( buf2, sizeof( buf2 ), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", &tm2 );`